# Swift - Realm Deleting/Updating based on condition in filter

Tags: ios, database, xcode, realm, swift5

I Want to delete Object with Nested condition
Some_Object -> some_array -> Compare with id

This is my JSON, I don't understand how to set condition for nested JSON.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1606213636.830863",
    "name": "Adwait  Barkale",
    "some_object": {
      "some_array": [
        {
          "id": "1606213636.830755", //Compare with this id
          "title": "Array 1 Title",
          "value": "Array 1 Value"
        },
        {
          "id": "1606213636.8308291",
          "title": "Array 2 Title",
          "value": "Array 2 Value"
        }
      ],
      "id": "1606213636.830851",
      "title": "Some Title",
      "some_double": 12345.056,
      "some_integer": 12
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1606213640.999922",
    "name": "Adwait  Barkale",
    "some_object": {
      "some_array": [
        {
          "id": "1606213640.9997969",
          "title": "Array 1 Title",
          "value": "Array 1 Value"
        },
        {
          "id": "1606213640.9998698",
          "title": "Array 2 Title",
          "value": "Array 2 Value"
        }
      ],
      "id": "1606213640.999902",
      "title": "Some Title",
      "some_double": 12345.056,
      "some_integer": 12
    }
  },
  {
    "age": "22",
    "id": "1606214033.621707",
    "some_object": {
      "some_array": [
        {
          "id": "1606214033.62157",
          "title": "Array 1 Title",
          "value": "Array 1 Value"
        },
        {
          "id": "1606214033.621667",
          "title": "Array 2 Title",
          "value": "Array 2 Value"
        }
      ],
      "id": "1606214033.621692",
      "title": "This is New Title",
      "some_double": 12345.056,
      "some_integer": 12
    },
    "name": "Adwait  Barkale"
  }
]
```

This is my Code.
How can i delete all the object having some_Object.some_array.id = something.
I don't Understand what should be there in the filter Condition.

```
      func deleteObject()
    {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let obj = realm.objects(MainModelClass.self).filter("some_object.some_array[0].id = '1606213636.830755'") //This Filter Condition to be updated
        if obj.count > 0{
            try! realm.write{
                
                realm.delete(obj)
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Realm doesn't store it's data as JSON - realm uses Realm objects so we would need to see what your MainModelClass looks like. Also `.filter("some_object` doesn't work for realm as filters are on Object properties so perhaps you mean `.filter("some_property`?

Comment: Then how can i apply that condition on realm.
some_object.some_Array.id
How can i reach here ??

Comment: Please remove the JSON from the question as it doesn't apply, then update the question (per my above comment) with your Realm object(s). What you're asking is not clear so adding the models may help us understand.